# How to configure Android to act as server in the local network?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, web-server

I have two devices (an Android phone and an Orange Pi) connected to the same Wi-Fi network via the notebook's hotspot. I do have a server running on the Android device which I want to make accessible to the Orange Pi. How do I do that?

As far as I know Android doesn't have a firewall or anything like that. Accessing the server via IP opens the server OK, but on the Orange Pi, I get that "cannot find host" error and can't ping the Android's IP address. What am I missing? How do I fix that?

Comment: What kind of server is running on the android device? SMTP? FTP? HTTP? Minecraft?

Comment: @Gantendo http using KSWEB app

Comment: When you say "accessing the server via IP" is that from the Android phone ir another device on the LAN?

Comment: I don't know quite enough about Android to know precisely how they handle firewalling but they REQUIRE a firewall to work because iptables/equivalent (ie Linux/android firewall) are required to implement NAT so hotspot clients can share the WAN address.  Its also entirely plausible that your hotspot is implementing network isolation depending on the vendor [more firewalling but done at a lower level - this can be implemented in hostapd - the program typically used to create a hotspot/ap ]. Also, I think this question belongs on android.stackexchange.

Comment: You should add your make, model and Android version to your question.

Comment: What OS is running on the notebook and thus providing the hotspot?